# SWT Java: how to change colour of text in Label control?

Tags: java, fonts, colors, swt, label

I know how to change size, style but how can I set colour of text in Label control? Here is my code so far:

```
Label myLabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
myLabel.setText("some text that needs to be for example green");
FontData[] fD = myLabel.getFont().getFontData();
fD[0].setHeight(16);
fD[0].setStyle(SWT.BOLD);
myLabel.setFont( new Font(display,fD[0]));
```

I see there is no colour property in FontData class.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Make sure you don't mix SWT and AWT colors, and if you build a `Color` object, make sure you dispose it.  You want something like:

```
final Color myColor = new Color(getDisplay(), 102, 255, 102);
myLabel.setForeground(color);
myLabel.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {
    public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e)
    {
        myColor.dispose();
    }
});
```

Or you can just use the built-in system colors:

```
myLabel.setForeground(getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN));
```

(Do not dispose the system colors.)

Answer (score 2):

```
myLabel.setForeground(Color fg).
```

color : The Color class is used to encapsulate colors in the default sRGB color space or colors in arbitrary color spaces identified by a ColorSpace.

For more information : [see this](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/Color/sRGB.html)

For green it'd be something like : `myLabel.setForeground(new org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color(getDisplay(), 102, 255, 102));`

Comment: Don't mix AWT `Color` with SWT `Color`.  You want `new org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color(getDisplay(), 102, 255, 102))`.  And you need to `dispose` the `Color` when you're done with it.